# Team Projects not longer exist?

Tags: tfs

We just built a new TFS 2017 server, and I am trying to organize the projects in my collection with team projects (So all web projects are in one folder, client server in another, etc, etc).

The issue I am having is that it looks like all projects are now considered team projects.  I can create a new project, but it will always be in the root of the collection.

Am i just missing something, or did Microsoft remove that functionality?

Thanks

Comment: How did you create the project, through web or VS?

Comment: through the web.

Comment: Then create project in web portal equal creating team project in Team Explorer , you have to create project through Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Different Team Projects shouldn't be used to organize different parts of an application. A Team Project is a container object in which you can create multiple teams. The Team Project can also contain multiple backlogs, Kanban boards, code repositories, builds, releases and tests.

I would recommend that you use a single Team Project and then use the resources within a Team Project to structure your application.

Comment: I am not looking at a single application (I would just use projects in the solution to handle different aspects of a single app)  I'm looking at multiple separate applications they just have a very rough item in common (such as the language used).

Comment: Then my comment still applies. If those applications are build by one organization you can choose for one single Team project and then use teams to separate the artifacts: https://nkdagility.com/one-team-project/

Answer (score 0):

Team Project still exists, if you **create project** in **web portal** such as below screenshot, it's equal **creating team project** in Team Explorer Visual Studio.

[image]

[image]

More details please refer this tutorial in MSDN: [Create a team project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/create-team-project?tabs=vsts)

If you just want to create a new project under a solution, you should do this directly in Visual Studio(Eclipse).  Either through solution page in solution explorer or directly in **File--New--Project**:

[image]

[image]